# When I add a configurable product the category is deconfigured, could someone please help me

Tags: category

[image]

**if you notice there is nothing in the head in the footer, did anyone have the same problem?**

Comment: Please check your apache or nginx error log, this is for sure a PHP error

Comment: Excuse me, how can I see that? can you help me please

Comment: it depends on your configuration, i my case i use ubuntu with apache. And my server logs are in /var/log/apache/
You can also check your exception.log located in your project (MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/exception.log)

Comment: [2020-09-29 18:02:03] main.CRITICAL: The element "category.product.type.details.renderers" can't have a child because "category.product.type.details.renderers" already has a child with alias "configurable". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"category.product.type.details.renderers\" can't have a child because \"category.product.type.details.renderers\" already has a child with alias \"configurable\". at /home/tacticalstore/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []

Comment: Do you use ElasticSuite? Seems to be the same error described here: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/252
If not, check your catalog_category_view.xml customisations, there might be a wrong node inside category.product.type.details.renderers node

Comment: thanks but there is no solution